# Merge multiple arrays from one array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do multiple arrays in a single array merge an array?

**how to end up with this**

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

*These codes*

```
[  
  [
    1,
    2
  ],
  [
    3,
    4
  ],
  [
    5,
    6
  ]
]
```

Comment: You can use `.flat()` if using mordern browsers

Comment: If you want to write a function which converts an array of arbitrarily nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers. e.g. [[1,2,[3]],4] -> [1,2,3,4].

```function flatten(elements) {
  return elements.reduce((result, current) => {
    return result.concat(Array.isArray(current) ? flatten(current) : current);
  }, []);
};``` Upvote this comment if this helped your work.